# Resetting DIV positions within a JQuery animated banner

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to build the most simple JQuery banner rotator. I have two divs that I want to rotate, so I did this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
window.setInterval (changeBanner, 3000);

function changeBanner() {
    $( ".homeBanners").animate({
        left: "-=968"
    }, 1000, function() {

        });
    }
})
```

I have wrapped these divs in a container like this:

```
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='homeBanners'>
        <div class="homeBanner1">

        </div>
        <div class="homeBanner2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 968px;
    height: 397px;
}
.homeBanners {
    position: relative;
    width: 1936px;
}
.homeBanner1 {
    float: left;
}
.homeBanner2 {
    float: left;
}
```

My question is. How do I "reset" the .homeBanner1 then the .homeBanner2 to it's original positions, so the animation can flow endlessly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an simple fix of your jQuery to make it work

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.setInterval (changeBanner, 3000);

  function changeBanner() {
    $( ".homeBanners").animate({
      left: "-=968"
    }, 1000, function() {
      $('.homeBanners > div').last().after($('.homeBanners > div').first());
      $(".homeBanners").attr('style', "left: 0");
    });
  }
});
```

A demo can be see here [on JSBin](http://jsbin.com/umeteq/6/edit). However, you can see another tutorial about **jQuery infinite slider** to get more suggestion about your work.

Comment: Wow, that's perfect. I don't undestand how that programing works, but it works just fine!
Guess I need to study a little bit more of Jquery.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

When I did this before, I copied the first element and appended it to the end of my list. That way you can scroll left (or right) continuously as once you reach your duplicate, you can immediately switch to the original. It'll show no visual change, but it'll put you right at the beginning of your list. A good solution should also calculate the number of slides and their widths automatically so that it'll still work even if you change them. With that in mind, **I've [made a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kpcUT/1/)**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    window.setInterval(changeBanner, 3000);

    var $firstBanner = $(".homeBanners > div:first");
    $firstBanner.clone().appendTo(".homeBanners");

    var $banners = $(".homeBanners > div"),
        bannerLength = $banners.length,
        bannerWidth = $firstBanner.width(),
        endPoint = -bannerWidth * (bannerLength - 1);

    function changeBanner() {
        if ($(".homeBanners").css("left") == endPoint + "px") {
            $(".homeBanners").css("left", "0");
        }
        $(".homeBanners").animate({
            left: "-=" + bannerWidth
        }, 1000, function () {});
    }
})
```